# How to create an instance of a class nested within Static class which is in turn nested within Non-Static class?

Tags: java, class, static, linked-list

How to create an instance of Node in following?

```
public class RemoveDups_1{

    public static class LinkedList{

        static int i = 5;

        class Node{

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class `RemoveDups_1` (which name does not conform to the conventions) is not a "non-static" class, it's a top-level class. There's no such thing as a "static top-level" class, so no one describes a top-level class as "non-static". It's not a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is a very strange way to work with objects, but if you are interested to create an instance of Node class you could achieve it in this way:

```
RemoveDups_1.LinkedList linkedList = new RemoveDups_1.LinkedList();
RemoveDups_1.LinkedList.Node node = linkedList.new Node();
```

Source: [Oracle documentation about nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)